# Android things lcd config

Tags: raspberry-pi, android-things

I'm trying to get a 5" LCD working with my raspberry pi 3 and Android Things Developer Preview 4.1.

I've added this to my config.txt:

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
```

All I get is a white screen with some artifacts:
[image]

It's not a cable issue, I can use the screen with my Windows PC just fine.

I've found some maybe relevant lines in logcat:

```
01-01 00:00:19.529 412-412/? I/SystemServiceManager: Starting com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService
01-01 00:00:19.568 412-434/? I/DisplayManagerService: Display device added: DisplayDeviceInfo{"Built-in Screen": uniqueId="local:0", 800 x 480, modeId 1, defaultModeId 1, supportedModes [{id=1, width=800, height=480, fps=60.000004}], colorTransformId 1, defaultColorTransformId 1, supportedColorTransforms [{id=1, colorTransform=0}], HdrCapabilities android.view.Display$HdrCapabilities@192777c, density 160, 160.0 x 160.42105 dpi, appVsyncOff 0, presDeadline 17666666, touch INTERNAL, rotation 0, type BUILT_IN, state UNKNOWN, FLAG_DEFAULT_DISPLAY, FLAG_ROTATES_WITH_CONTENT, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
01-01 00:00:19.571 412-434/? I/DisplayManagerService: Display device changed state: "Built-in Screen", ON
01-01 00:00:23.990 412-434/? I/WindowManager: No existing display settings /data/system/display_settings.xml; starting empty
```

I've bought the screen from an [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5-Inch-800x480-HDMI-Touch-LCD-Screen-Display-For-Raspberry-Pi-Pi2-Model-B-A/282004253365) seller. It came with a dvd, and had a [sample config.txt](https://pastebin.com/PRv9xp4J) file, it suggests the same settings.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I gave up. Now I use the screen with my windows pc. Touch input does not work with windows, but at least the display is usable.